# How to Angular.js controller from C#

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have Windows service written in C# that basically acts as a timer to fire an event. **When the service fires I need to call a Angular.js controller** passing variable(s) and receive a PDF file back as the response. I'm new to Angular so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The way you worded this is hard to understand. The server can't "call a controller". Perhaps you mean something with websockets, where when the server sends data over the socket, your Angular app will respond by, perhaps, visiting some related route where it does whatever you want with that PDF. By the way, huge win for using "controller" as a verb in your title. Bro, do you even controller?

Comment: this question is confusing.  Are you saying that you want your server to ask angular to find a PDF file on the client's machine and send it back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Angular lives on the client side in the web browser (well, typically anyway) so if you want to communicate to it from your C# service you need to find a way to send and receive information between your server (running the service) and the client browser.

How you can go about this depends on your project's needs, but for timed events you're probably best off using websockets to perform this communication. If you're working in C# you might want to check out SignalR for your backend.